# How to set mandatory choices to navigate to the next screen?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

The main screen of my app has three questions:

1- A question with 6 choices in a dropdown named ***Office***.

2- A question where the user picks one of the departments with 6 checkboxes.

3- A question with 9 choices in a dropdown named ***Type***.

When the user is done selecting the answers the ***Next*** button can be pressed.
However, I would like the survey to only allow the user to go to the next screen after he picks an  answer for each question.

Here is the code that I have in the ***ONSELECT*** section of the button.

`Switch(Type.Selected.Value,"360", Navigate('360',ScreenTransition.None));Switch(Type.Selected.Value,"Report", Navigate(ReportRequest_Main,ScreenTransition.None));Switch(Type.Selected.Value,"Bulk", Navigate(Bulk,ScreenTransition.None));Switch(Type.Selected.Value,"Changereport", Navigate(ChangeReport,ScreenTransition.None));Switch(Type.Selected.Value,"Grouping", Navigate(Grouping,ScreenTransition.None));Switch(Type.Selected.Value,"Recode", Navigate(Recode,ScreenTransition.None));Switch(Type.Selected.Value,"View", Navigate(VP,ScreenTransition.None))`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a condition of the below pattern in the Next button's Visible or DisplayMode property:

```
Not(Or(IsBlankOrError(Type.SelectedItems), IsBlankOrError(Office.SelectedItems),...))
```